# Countif function in VBA not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range where i need to filter by the id number in the first column and then check if the next column contains entity type which is either "T" or "H" so i wrote a code like this but on the countif line gives an error of 1004 if i run the code

Kindly help where i'm going wrong

```
MyRange.Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Copy
Range("R21").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Selection.RemoveDuplicates (1)

For Each jn In Selection
    MyRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=jn

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), "T") <> 0 Then
 MyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

End if
```

Comment: What is the *jn* filter?

Comment: jn are the index numbers for the journals in the first column as the first column contains more than one  journal numbers so i removed duplicate in range "R 21" then filter the journal range by the every Journal Numbers

Comment: You might want to change worksheetfunction for application. That way if the counift throws an error, it won't raise one on your code. I'd even link that countif to an integer variable, si if it stays 0 (error or result 0) will do the trick.